# Unclear figure plotting error in matplotlib 3D

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, error-handling, matplotlib-widget

I'm trying to better understand 3D plotting using various tutorials online. I tried to recreate one of these online tutorials, [this one in particular](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/make-3d-interactive-matplotlib-plot-in-jupyter-notebook/) by running some of the code in my own Jupyter Notebook, however, when I try this I get a suspicious error.

I am running the first code block from the website (attached below) and I get this eror whenever I try and run it. This error is unclear to me so I am having trouble resolving it!

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-304-35f6bb1e64fb> in <module>
     20 
     21 # creating figure
---> 22 fig = plt.figure()
     23 ax = Axes3D(fig)
     24 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in figure(num, figsize, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, frameon, FigureClass, clear, **kwargs)
    538     If there is an active figure, it will be updated and displayed before the
    539     pause, and the GUI event loop (if any) will run during the pause.
--> 540 
    541     This can be used for crude animation.  For more complex animation use
    542     :mod:`matplotlib.animation`.

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py in new_figure_manager(cls, num, *args, **kwargs)
   3356 
   3357         Parameters
-> 3358         ----------
   3359         tool : tool_like
   3360             The tool to add, see `.ToolManager.get_tool`.

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipympl/backend_nbagg.py in new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, figure)
    485         if 'nbagg.transparent' in rcParams and rcParams['nbagg.transparent']:
    486             figure.patch.set_alpha(0)
--> 487         manager = FigureManager(canvas, num)
    488 
    489         if is_interactive():

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipympl/backend_nbagg.py in __init__(self, canvas, num)
    459         FigureManagerWebAgg.__init__(self, canvas, num)
    460         self.web_sockets = [self.canvas]
--> 461         self.toolbar = Toolbar(self.canvas)
    462 
    463     def show(self):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipympl/backend_nbagg.py in __init__(self, canvas, *args, **kwargs)
    120     def __init__(self, canvas, *args, **kwargs):
    121         DOMWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
--> 122         NavigationToolbar2WebAgg.__init__(self, canvas, *args, **kwargs)
    123 
    124         self.on_msg(self.canvas._handle_message)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_webagg_core.py in __init__(self, canvas)
    395         self.message = ''
    396         self._cursor = None  # Remove with deprecation.
--> 397         super().__init__(canvas)
    398 
    399     def set_message(self, message):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py in __init__(self, canvas)
   2706         elif button_name in rcParams['keymap.forward']:
   2707             toolbar.forward()
-> 2708 
   2709 
   2710 class NonGuiException(Exception):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py in _init_toolbar(self)
   2769 
   2770             figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(
-> 2771                 figure.canvas.manager.button_press_handler_id)
   2772     """
   2773 

NotImplementedError:
```

(Here's the code)

```
# creating 3d plot using matplotlib 
# in python
  
# for creating a responsive plot
%matplotlib widget
  
# importing required libraries
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  
# creating random dataset
xs = [14, 24, 43, 47, 54, 66, 74, 89, 12,
      44, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5]
  
ys = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 6, 3,
      5, 2, 4, 1, 8, 7, 0, 5]
  
zs = [9, 6, 3, 5, 2, 4, 1, 8, 7, 0, 1, 2, 
      3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
  
# creating figure
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
  
# creating the plot
plot_geeks = ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs, color='green')
  
# setting title and labels
ax.set_title("3D plot")
ax.set_xlabel('x-axis')
ax.set_ylabel('y-axis')
ax.set_zlabel('z-axis')
  
# displaying the plot
plt.show()
```

I have made sure I downloaded the correct libraries and I checked to see what version of python I was running, 3.8.3.

Comment: just a suggestion but are you not using `%matplolib inline` in your notebook? I have a feeling that might be the issue but not completely sure

Answer (score 0):

Use the magic functions
%matplotlib inline

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).